# GNU make: ifeq inside a call function

Tags: makefile

I want to write a call function something like this

```
define run  
  @echo "running" > $1  
ifeq ("$(var)" "var1")  
  @echo "var1" > $1  
else  
  @echo "var2" > $1  
endif  
endef
```

Problem is I am not able to figure out from make documents how to use ifeq inside a call function, or if there is any better solution than using ifeq.

Comment: A function to be used with `call` is one thing; a "canned" sequence of commands to be expanded in a recipe is another. They have different syntax. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to use a canned sequence of commands to be expanded in a recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a conditional in a canned sequence of commands is a pain. It's much easier to resolve the conditional outside:

```
define run
@echo "running" > $(log)
@echo $(var) > $(log)
endef

targ: log := 23B.log
targ: var := var1
targ:
    $(run)
```